# Spring for Android throws null HttpClientErrorException

Tags: android, spring, basic-authentication, android-networking

I'm new in SO and in android development.

First of all, I apologize if my grammar or my spelling is not correct. I'm not an English native speaker.

I'm trying to do an `HTTP GET request` through **Spring for Android**. All seems to work OK until I tried to catch the exception that is thrown when an error occurs (`HttpClientErrorException`), such as a 401 (`HTTP 401 UNAUTHORIZED`).

For some reason, Spring for Android throws this exception as `null`.

To be more explicit, this is my code:

```
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        String url = "http://192.168.0.105:8080/guniv/rest/test";

        String username = eTextUsername.getText().toString();
        String password = eTextPassword.getText().toString();

        // Setting Http BasicAuth headers
        HttpAuthentication authHeader = new HttpBasicAuthentication(username, password);
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setAuthorization(authHeader);
        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());


        // Doing request!!
        try {
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
            Log.i("INFO", response.getBody());
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) { // e is null!!
            String message = "";
            if( e.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED ) 
                message = "Incorrect username or password.";

            //do something here...

        } 

        return 0; // TODO
    }
```

Well, when some HTTP error occurs, and the `HttpClientErrorException` is catched, it results to be `null` and obviously `e.getStatusCode()` throws `NullPointerException`.

Somebody had this issue before?

Thanks, and sorry again for my English!